# Amazon Sagemaker open json from S3 bucket

Tags: python, json, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

I created a S3 bucket and placed both a `data.csv` and a `data.json` file inside it. I then created a Sagemaker notebook and specified this S3 bucket in the IAM role.

This now works from inside the notebook:

```
import pandas as pd
from sagemaker import get_execution_role

bucket='my-sagemaker-bucket'
data_key = 'data.csv'
data_location = 's3://{}/{}'.format(bucket, data_key)
data = pd.read_csv(data_location)
```

But this errors saying file doesn't exist:

```
import json
from sagemaker import get_execution_role

bucket='my-sagemaker-bucket'
data_key = 'data.json'
data_location = 's3://{}/{}'.format(bucket, data_key)
data = json.load(open(data_location))
```

Anyone know why I can read the csv but not the json? I also can't `shutil.copy` the csv to the notebook's current working directory (also says file doesn't exist). I'm not very well versed with S3 buckets or Sagemaker, so not sure if this is a permissions/policy issue or something else.

Answer (score 2):

your SageMaker-ExecutionRole might have insufficient rights to access your S3-bucket. The default IAM-SageMaker Execution role has the permission: "AmazonSageMakerFullAccess" which uses the S3 RequestCondition "s3:ExistingObjectTag/SageMaker = true".

So maybe you could try to simply tag your S3 bucket (Tag: SageMaker:true). Control your IAM settings.

```
import pandas as pd

bucket='my-sagemaker-bucket'
data_key = 'data.json'
data_location = 's3://{}/{}'.format(bucket, data_key)

pd.read_json(data_location) # , orient='columns', typ='series'
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas can handle S3 URL using your AWS credentials. So you could use `pd.read_csv` or `pd.read_json` instead of `json.load`. The suggestion from @Michael_S should work.